# Run Simple shiny app in java dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have created a simple shiny app and I want to run this app from java dynamic web project. To achieve this I have included the required code in index.html. I am able to get No of Bins slider, but not getting the plot. Is this possible to run a shiny app from dynamic web project directly in the browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0];ionrangeslider[2.1.6];strftime[0.9.2];bootstrap[3.3.7]</script>

  <script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="shared/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>


<link href="shared/ionrangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="shared/ionrangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinShiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="shared/ionrangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>


<script src="shared/strftime/strftime-min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>  <title>Old Faithful Geyser Data</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Old Faithful Geyser Data</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form class="well">
          <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
            <label class="control-label" for="bins">Number of bins:</label>
            <input class="js-range-slider" id="bins" data-min="1" data-max="50" data-from="30" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="9.8" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-prettify-enabled="true" data-keyboard="true" data-data-type="number"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div id="distPlot" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 100% ; height: 400px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A shiny app is more than raw HTML. If you take the html of a shiny app and save it as a file and try to open that file in s browser, it will render, but it will not be functional/interactive. That's because shiny requires a backend server--an R process--to power it and send the output to the page. Without an R process running a shiny server, it's just a static HTML page. You can host your app online (on shinyapps.io or on a shiny server) and use an iframe inside your java app that points to the shiny app.